# Liftings and closed immersions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $A$ be a flat $\mathbf{Z}_p$-algebra, $\overline{I}\subset A/p$ an ideal.

Can we find an ideal $I\subset A$ such that

- $I$ mod $p$ = $\overline{I}$
- $I$ does **not** contain $p$.

It's harder than it looks. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $A=\mathbf{Z}_p[x,y]/(xy-p)$ and $\bar I = (x,y)$. Suppose $I$ lifts $\bar I$ and does not contain $p$; let $I'=(I,p^2)$, which has the same property as $I$. Then the $\mathbf{Z}/p^2$-algebra $B=A/I'$ satisfies $B/p\cong \mathbf{F}_p$, $p^2 B = 0$ and $pB\neq 0$, so we have $B\cong \mathbf{Z}/p^2\mathbf{Z}$. The map $A\to B=\mathbf{Z}/p^2\mathbf{Z}$ furnishes a solution $(x,y)\in (p\mathbf{Z}/p^2\mathbf{Z})^2$ of the equation $xy=p$, but there are none. Contradiction.

Comment: There are at least some solutions to $xy=p$ in $(\mathbb Z / p^2 \mathbb Z)^2$, for instance one always has $x=1, y=p$.  Or in the special case $p=5$, you have the nontrivial solution $x=3$, $y=10$.

Comment: Thanks! I meant solutions with $x$ and $y$ zero modulo $p$ ;)

Comment: Why do $x,y$ have to land in $pB$?

Comment: I think if you alter $A$ so that $A= \mathbb Z_p[\![x,y]\!] / (xy-p)$, then everything you want holds.  This is because now $A$ is local with max ideal $m=(x,y,p)$, and since $I$ doesn't contain $p$, $I \subseteq m$. The map $A \rightarrow B$ is then a local homomorphism, so the image is in $pB$, the maximal ideal of $B$.

Comment: By construction x and y are zero mod p because of the choice of $\bar I=(x,y)$.